# Removing Closed Form from a List in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, list

So, i have a question on using a list of forms and when a form closes, to remove itself from the list in C#.  I don't think the garbage collector does it automatically, right?

Let's say I have:

```
List<SomeGraphForm> GraphGroup = new List<SomeGraphForm>();

....
```

add the forms...

```
GraphGroup.Add(x);
```

When x closes, what is the cleanest way to remove it from the list?   Is using `FormClosed` event the best way (but I am not sure how to pass `SomeGraphForm` item back to the other class(es)).

Comment: Not really sure about your question but look at [Application.OpenForms Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms(v=vs.110).aspx), that could give you currently open forms in  application. **May be** you can use that instead of maintaining your own list of forms.

Comment: Hi,  basically it's a list of forms that are used as graphs for dynamic updates.   (same set of data but might be displayed differently).   So the user can be removing the forms dynamically or adding new forms and the list is used to update the graphs on all of them since they might be looking at a particular group of data.    So when the form is closed, just need the cleanest way to remove it from the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, the GC cannot collect something that is still referred to. I would go with this basic approach:

```
  //code to create and add form
  var form = new Form1();
  form.FormClosed +=form_FormClosed;
  _forms.Add(form);
  form.Show();

  //cleanup
  private void form_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
  {
        var closedForm = sender as Form1;
        _forms.Remove(closedForm);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a base class that you use to derive all forms from, you can unregister in the OnClosed method.

```
protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
    // unregister here
}
```